# How to make a "term reference" > "taxonomy vocab" display alphabetically in a content type?

Tags: entities, nodes, taxonomy-terms

Hello I have a content type that has a field type > term reference using the "Check Boxes/radios buttons" widget.

When adding content using that content type the checkboxes (which are of course being populated by a taxonomy) arn't being displayed in alphabetical order which will be difficult for my client to use. I've tried setting the taxomony to alphabetical but that doesn't seem to have any effect on its display within the content type.

Help appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the order (weight) of the terms within the vocabulary to be alphabetical.

I've just tried this and it works in D7.23 using a 'Term Reference' field. To test this I ordered terms into non-alphabetical, saved the vocabulary, then created a node. Terms were in the order I'd specified. I then 'reset to alphabetical', saved the vocabulary and created a node. Terms were now in alphabetical order.

I found your question title confusing as it talks about terms reference but then the question itself mentions node reference. Please edit the question and clarify.